# React router path issue

Tags: reactjs, path, router

**user and user/:id working correct but other paths doesnt work and redirect to user/:id page...**

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <TopMenu />
    <div className="page-container" style={style.content}>
      <div className="page-content">
        <Sidebar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />  
          <Route exact path="/user" component={ListUsers}/>
          <Route exact path="/user/:id" component={UserDetails} /> 
          <Route exact path="/user/create" component={AddNewUser} />
          <Route exact path="/user/roles" component={ListRoles} />
          <Route exact path="/user/roles/:id" component={RoleDetails} />
          <Route exact path="/user/role/create" component={AddNewRole} />         
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</Router>,
```

Answer (score 3):

These routes are the same, because you could have an `id = 'create'`

```
<Route exact path="/user/:id" component={UserDetails} /> 
<Route exact path="/user/create" component={AddNewUser} />
```

So you should match the more specific one first, so it matches before the variable one:

```
<Route exact path="/user/roles" component={ListRoles} />
<Route exact path="/user/role/create" component={AddNewRole} />         
<Route exact path="/user/roles/:id" component={RoleDetails} />
<Route exact path="/user/create" component={AddNewUser} />
<Route exact path="/user/:id" component={UserDetails} />
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `:id` could be anything, you need to put it *after* any static `/user/whatever` routes.

Answer (score 1):

Change your switch to

```
<Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />  
          <Route exact path="/user" component={ListUsers}/>
          <Route exact path="/user/create" component={AddNewUser} />
          <Route exact path="/user/roles" component={ListRoles} />
          <Route exact path="/user/role/create" component={AddNewRole} /> 
          <Route exact path="/user/roles/:id" component={RoleDetails} />
          <Route exact path="/user/:id" component={UserDetails} />         
        </Switch>
```

In your Switch the `:id` route was matching before the `create` and `roles` routes were tested.